# Does RMI support P2P

Tags: java, rmi

i want to create a P2P application where there is no central server and clients communicate directly with each other. Does RMI support P2P or not ...
Please do comment and also tell me how to do this project in RMI if possible.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

"P2P" is an architectural term. RMI is a protocol. The two are entirely independent of one another.

So yes, you can use RMI for P2P applications. You can use any protocol you like for P2P communications. RMI neither knows nor cares whether it's P2P or client-server, all it sees are two ends of a network connection.

If you have a more specific question, you might want to ask that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does:

http://www.java.net/project/p2p-rmi-over-jxta
http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/networking/jxta/jxtap2pch03.pdf

But the implication is that all the peers have to be Java, because they all need to understand RMI.  That could be a limiting factor.

Answer (score 0):

RMI objects are indeed all peers to each other. Each is its own server (conceptually; they actually share a server socket where it makes sense). However, all those objects still need to discover each other, and the easiest model there is more client-server.

The other issue of course is security; how do you trust the messages that are being sent by the other peers? That is, though, a problem in all P2P architectures.